# How to change the report table direction from right to left

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, reporting-services, rdlc

[image]

I want to make the `emp_num` is first column from right hand side and so on but i can't because of grouping :

I want to change this to :

> overtime | daystate  |expr(اليوم) | shiftName | empName | empNum

---

The code view :

```
<Tablix Name="Tablix2">
        <TablixBody>
          <TablixColumns>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1.9987in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1.64237in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1.29861in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width>1.1468in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
          </TablixColumns>
          <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.23958in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox7">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>المناوبة</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox7</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox9">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>اليوم</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox9</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox28">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>وصف اليوم</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox28</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox4">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>الاضافي</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox4</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox74">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox74</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox75">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox75</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox29">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox29</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox5">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox5</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.23958in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="shiftName">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!shiftName.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>shiftName</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="dayDate">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Format(Fields!dayDate.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd,dddd")</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <Language>ar-EG</Language>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>dayDate</rd:DefaultName>     
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="dayState">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!dayState.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>dayState</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="overtime">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=Fields!overtime.Value</Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>overtime</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox54">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox54</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <BackgroundColor>Silver</BackgroundColor>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox55">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style>
                                <Language>ar-EG</Language>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox55</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox56">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value />
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox56</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="Textbox57">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value>=(TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!overtime.Value)).Days * 24 +
 TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!overtime.Value)).Hours).ToString
  +":" + TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!overtime.Value)).Minutes.ToString("d2")</Value>
                              <Style>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                              </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                          </Style>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName>Textbox57</rd:DefaultName>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
          </TablixRows>
        </TablixBody>
        <TablixColumnHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember />
            <TablixMember>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixColumnHierarchy>
        <TablixRowHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <TablixHeader>
                <Size>0.69391in</Size>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Textbox80">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>رقم الموظف</Value>
                            <Style>
                              <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                            </Style>
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style>
                          <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                        </Style>
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox80</rd:DefaultName>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixHeader>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <TablixHeader>
                    <Size>1.43885in</Size>
                    <CellContents>
                      <Textbox Name="Textbox71">
                        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                        <Paragraphs>
                          <Paragraph>
                            <TextRuns>
                              <TextRun>
                                <Value>اسم الموظف</Value>
                                <Style>
                                  <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                </Style>
                              </TextRun>
                            </TextRuns>
                            <Style>
                              <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                            </Style>
                          </Paragraph>
                        </Paragraphs>
                        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox71</rd:DefaultName>
                      </Textbox>
                    </CellContents>
                  </TablixHeader>
                  <TablixMembers>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <FixedData>true</FixedData>
                      <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    </TablixMember>
                  </TablixMembers>
                  <FixedData>true</FixedData>
                  <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
                  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
              <FixedData>true</FixedData>
              <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
              <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="empNum">
                <GroupExpressions>
                  <GroupExpression>=Fields!empNum.Value</GroupExpression>
                </GroupExpressions>
              </Group>
              <SortExpressions>
                <SortExpression>
                  <Value>=Fields!empName.Value</Value>
                </SortExpression>
              </SortExpressions>
              <TablixHeader>
                <Size>0.69391in</Size>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="empNum">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!empNum.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style>
                          <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
                        </Style>
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>empNum</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixHeader>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="empName">
                    <GroupExpressions>
                      <GroupExpression>=Fields!empName.Value</GroupExpression>
                    </GroupExpressions>
                  </Group>
                  <SortExpressions>
                    <SortExpression>
                      <Value>=Fields!empName.Value</Value>
                    </SortExpression>
                  </SortExpressions>
                  <TablixHeader>
                    <Size>1.43885in</Size>
                    <CellContents>
                      <Textbox Name="empName">
                        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                        <Paragraphs>
                          <Paragraph>
                            <TextRuns>
                              <TextRun>
                                <Value>=Fields!empName.Value</Value>
                                <Style />
                              </TextRun>
                            </TextRuns>
                            <Style>
                              <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
                            </Style>
                          </Paragraph>
                        </Paragraphs>
                        <rd:DefaultName>empName</rd:DefaultName>
                      </Textbox>
                    </CellContents>
                  </TablixHeader>
                  <TablixMembers>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <FixedData>true</FixedData>
                      <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                      <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Group Name="Details" />
                      <TablixMembers>
                        <TablixMember />
                      </TablixMembers>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <KeepWithGroup>Before</KeepWithGroup>
                    </TablixMember>
                  </TablixMembers>
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixRowHierarchy>
        <RepeatColumnHeaders>true</RepeatColumnHeaders>
        <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
        <SortExpressions>
          <SortExpression>
            <Value>=Fields!empName.Value</Value>
          </SortExpression>
        </SortExpressions>
        <Top>1.34375in</Top>
        <Left>0.13021in</Left>
        <Height>0.97916in</Height>
        <Width>8.21924in</Width>
      </Tablix>
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't any easy way to achieve this. There is however a possible workaround to accomplish your wanted result.
You could add an extra row above use that to place your parent column values in.

> 1. Add the Group in the groups section.
>      A new column to the left will appear which isn't what you wanted but don't leave that new section just yet.
> 2. Right-click and insert a new Row.
>      This row is now also part of the Parent Group and can have the grouped headers displayed in any column or place inside of it by using an aggregate expression for example. You could add a couple of extra empty columns add the end and place the fields above it there, so you get the exact mirror of your current layout.
> 3. Right-click the unwanted left (grouping) column and delete it. Be careful to only delete the column and NOT the associated group level.

Placing the children columns in the right order should be very straightforward but if anything is still unclear, just let me know and I'll update.

Answer (score 4):

Click On The first cell of the table (at top left corner) to select the table and then in Properties windows under Localization change LayoutDirection  to RTL

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose the reportviewer in the winform. In the properties, on 'Right to left' choose "Yes".
You will see the result just while running.

Comment: Not working....